# XmlReader convert to good type tagged by xsi type

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I need some help to find the good way to use `XmlReader`. I have a simple XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ExtranetConfig xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <DataParametersGroup GroupName="test">
    <DataParameter Name="testPrm" SqlParamName=":testPrm">
      <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">thisIsMyParam</Value>
      <AdditionalValues>
        <Description xsi:type="xsd:string">My Description</Description>
        <Id xsi:type="xsd:int">10</Id>
      </AdditionalValues>
    </DataParameter>
  </DataParametersGroup>
</ExtranetConfig>
```

For some reasons, I must serialize a part of it

```
  <AdditionalValues>
    <Description xsi:type="xsd:string">My Description</Description>
    <Id xsi:type="xsd:int">10</Id>
  </AdditionalValues>
```

with a custom class which implements `IXmlSerializable`. But, I don't understand how to get the good type for `Description` and `Id` nodes with the `XmlReader`.

This is my last code test, in my custom class:

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
        {
            reader.MoveToElement();

            var readElement = reader.ReadSubtree();
            readElement.MoveToContent();

            XmlNamespaceManager nsmanager = new XmlNamespaceManager(readElement.NameTable);
            nsmanager.AddNamespace("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
            nsmanager.AddNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");            

            do
            {             
                if (readElement.HasValue)
                {

                    var val2 = readElement.ReadContentAs(readElement.ValueType, nsmanager);                   
                    var name2 = readElement.Name;
                    dictionary.Add(name2, val2);
                }
            }
            while (readElement.Read());
        }
```

My goal is to add to the dictionary all the elements between 
`<AdditionalValues></AdditionalValues>`. Current code is partially doing the job, but always deserialize in string type.

Comment: Do you know the set of types that could appear in the dictionary?  What are they?  Do you need to serialize as well as deserialize?

Comment: Are you looking for a general solution that allows any known type to appear as a value in the dictionary, or are you only looking for deserialize dictionaries with integer and string values?

Comment: In my case i ll use only primary types, but make it generic with any serializable type referenced by xml namespace should be great.

Answer (score 0):

this is my actual solution, but i assume it is not a clean one, it's "hardcoded"..

```
  private readonly Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

...

```
    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        reader.MoveToElement();
        string type = null;
        string name = null;
        object result = null;
        while (reader.Read())
        {

            if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element))
            {
                type = reader.GetAttribute("xsi:type");
                name = reader.Name; 
            }
            if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text))
            {
                if (type != null)
                {
                    switch (type.ToLower())
                    {
                        case "xsd:int":
                            result = reader.ReadContentAsInt();
                            break;
                        case "xsd:double":
                            result = reader.ReadContentAsDouble();
                            break;
                        case "xsd:float":
                            result = reader.ReadContentAsFloat();
                            break;
                        case "xsd:string":
                            result = reader.ReadContentAsString();
                            break;
                        case "xsd:datetime":
                            result = reader.ReadContentAsDateTime();
                            break;
                        case "xsd:boolean":
                            result = reader.ReadContentAsBoolean();
                            break;
                        default:
                            result = reader.ReadContentAsString();
                            break;
                    }
                    dictionary.Add(name, result);
                }               
            }
            if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement))
            {
                if(reader.Name =="AdditionalValues")
                {
//Edit - add read before break or deserialisation will end here.
reader.Read();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I dont understand how to work with namespaces and get type attribute with XmlReader, reader.ValueType is always (it is default value) System.String..